# React-router: How nested routes work?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nested-routes

I have a react application with react-router. I am trying to setup nested routes:

```
"/" --> home page
"/products" --> products list (child component of home page)
"/products/new" --> new product: child component of products list
```

What I tried to do so far:

```
<Route path="/" component="home" >

     <Route path="products" component="products" >

           <Route path="new" component="products_new" />
     </Route>

</Route>
```

Now in the browser from my default home page, when I hit `"/products"`, the products component is loaded and I can see my list of products. But when I hit `"products/new"` nothing happens. I get a blank page. If I hit `"/new"` (not nested) it works (page product_new is loaded inside its parent).
(this `"/products/new"` does not work; this `"/new"` works)

I had a look to this question on github
[Problem with nested routes #687](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mfx7.png). The solution says:

> I discovered my problem. Parent routes are always called. Thats the
>   intent. But child components need to have repeated
>   `<Router.RouteHandler/>` to get rendered.

I cannot understand this solution. What does it mean: 
***"but child components need to have repeated
`<Router.RouteHandler/>` to get rendered"***

**EDIT1:**
Here are my components (routers and views):

1. My routing hierarchy:

   ```
               <Route path="/" >    
                       <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                       <Route path="products">
                           <IndexRoute component={Products} />
                           <Route path="new" component={Products_New} />
                       </Route>
                   </Route>                        
               </Router>
   ```
2. My home component:

   ```
        <div className="col-lg-12">
           <h1>Home page</h1>
           <hr />
           {this.props.children}
       </div>
   ```
3. My products components:

   ```
       <div>
           <div className="col-lg-12">
               <h1>Products</h1>
           </div>
           <hr />
           {this.props.children}
       </div>
   ```
4. My product-new component:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Have you had a look at IndexRoutes? If not, have a read about it on the [**official documentation**](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/08-index-routes). Your problem here is that when you visit `/products/new`, react-router tries to render **all** components that are above your `products_new` route.

This behavior is intended if you want to render a child component **inside** the parent component. Allow me to demonstrate with a couple of examples:

#### Example 1

Consider the following `home` component which has a Header and a Footer which is included on all pages.

```
<Header />
<div>{this.props.children}</div>
</Footer />
```

with the following routing:

```
<Route path="/" component={home} >
  <Route path="products" component={products} />
</Route>
```

- Visiting `/` would render a page with just a `<Header />`, an empty `<div>` and `<Footer />`.
- Visiting `/products` would render a page like above, but the `<div>` would now **contain** your `<Products />` component.

Since, in your code you (probably) don't render `{this.props.children}` you will always get the parent `<Home />` component, regardless if you visited `/` or `/products`.

This behavior is useful for stuff that wrap the main elements of your site, such as menus, banners, sidebars, etc.

---

#### Example 2

Now again consider the same `home` component:

```
<Header />
<div>{this.props.children}</div>
</Footer />
```

but with this routing:

```
<Route path="/">
  <IndexRoute component={home}
  <Route path="products" component={products} />
</Route>
```

- Visiting `/` would render a page with just a `<Header />`, an empty `<div>` and `<Footer />`.
- Visiting `/products` would now render your `<Products />` component **on its own**, without being wrapped inside the parent `<Home />` component.

---

#### TL;DR

If you instead want each route to render individual components, and not everything under the tree of that route, you should use the following routing instead:

```
const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({basename: '/'});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Route history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/">
      <IndexRoute component={home} />
      <Route path="products" >
        <IndexRoute component={products} />
        <Route path="new" component={products_new} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I did what you told me but unfortunately it still does not work. I forgot to say that this is a SPA (single Page App) So I changed browserHistory to hashHistory and now it is working (only I have a # in my url...

Comment: Right, you would need to use a `history`. I strongly recommend using `browserHistory` though. I updated my code above, try that.

Comment: I understand your answer. My intent is to have every view rendered inside its parent. My problem is:

why this url works: /products (by works I mean product-component is properly rendered inside home-component)

But this url does not work /products/new (I get a blank page although there is a placeholder ( {this.props.children} ) inside products-components. I would expect to have products-new-component rendered inside products-component which in turn would be rendered inside home-component

Comment: I have edited my answer. Now you can see:
- routing hierarchy
- home component
- products component
- products-new component

Comment: Please put your new code in your question, and not as an answer. You need to remove your IndexRoute under `products` and change `products` route to `<Route path="products" component={products} />`. That will give the routing you want.

Comment: Your "official documentation" link is broken.

Comment: @Tagc, indeed. Updated with the new link. Thanks!!