# Why React Component is rendering on same page instead of another?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, components, nested-routes

So All the components are rendering fine on new page except the nested route ones. Also the url changes but the component renders on the same page after all the components of previous page instead of rending on its own page.
here is the code

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <PlaylistState>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navigation />
          <main className="content-container">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Home />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/favourites">
                <Favourites />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/playlistForm">
                <PlaylistForm />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/playlists">
                <Library />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </main>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </PlaylistState>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Library.js**

```
const Library = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="my-2">Library</h1>
      <Playlists />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Library;
```

**Playlists.js**

```
const Playlists = () => {
  const PlaylistContext = useContext(playlistContext);
  const { playlists } = PlaylistContext;
  const { url, path } = useRouteMatch();

  // console.log(url);
  console.log("path", path);

  return (
    <section className="playlist-container">
      {playlists.map((playlist) => (
        <>
          <Link to={`${url}/${playlist.id}`}>
            <PlaylistCard key={playlist.id} cardDetails={playlist} />
          </Link>
        </>
      ))}

      <Route path={`${path}/:playlistId`}>
        <Playlist />
      </Route>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Playlists;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behavior of a nested route, it renders inside the parent component, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743916/react-router-how-nested-routes-work).

If you want the route `"/playlists/:playlistId"` to render only `<Playlist />`, you should have at the top level as a sibling to all the other routes.

EDIT: code

```js
    function App() {
      return (
        <PlaylistState>
          <Router>
            <div className="App">
              <Navigation />
              <main className="content-container">
                <Switch>
                  ...
                  <Route path="/playlists/:id">
                    <Playlist />
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/playlists">
                    <Library />
                  </Route>
                </Switch>
              </main>
            </div>
          </Router>
        </PlaylistState>
      );
    }
```

export default App;

Comment: So how can i render Playlist component to a new page? any idea

Comment: Just add it as another route inside the ```<Switch>```, and be sure to put that route before the more generic one, i.e. ```"/playlists"```

Comment: So Problem was not about nested routing at all my bad. But thanx for the time mate